# Launch a Docker container with a Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: windows, docker, scheduled-tasks

Is there any way to launch a Docker container in Windows using the Task Scheduler?  The majority of tutorials show this by using a crontab in Linux, is there a Windows alternative?

Answer (score 0):

A "Docker container on Windows" would support Windows images, not the usual Linux images (launched on a Linux host by a crontab)

You would need a full Docker on Windows solution, and I am not referring to [Docker for Mac and Windows Beta](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/), which would run a *Linux* (Alpine) host on a Hyper-V VM on Windows: that would not run any Windows image, only Linux images.

I am talking about Docker for Windows (provided your [Windows10 has the latest Hyper-V feature](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2016/04/01/build-2016-container-announcements-hyper-v-containers-and-windows-10-and-powershell-for-docker/)). Up to very recently, that was only possible on a [Windows Server 2016 TP4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/system_requirements).

---

2023: As noted by [Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553609/mathias-lykkegaard-lorenzen) in the comments:

> It is now possible to run Docker on Windows Server 2022 via WSL instead.

Comment: It is now possible to run Docker on Windows Server 2022 via WSL instead.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visible.